# KeyError in Python Code even though Key is present

Tags: python, json, key, keyerror

I am trying to create a Channel Separator code to separate the transcribe that is printed in a JSON file.

I have the following code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event:
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
        s3_object = event["Records"][0]["s3"]
        bucket_name = s3_object["bucket"]["name"]
        file_name = s3_object["object"]["key"]
        file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
        transcript_result = json.loads(file_obj["Body"].read())

        segmented_transcript = transcript_result["results"]["channel_labels"]
        items = transcript_result["results"]["items"]

        channel_text = []
        flag = False
        channel_json = {}
        for no_of_channel in range (segmented_transcript["number_of_channels"]):
            for word in items:
                for cha in segmented_transcript["channels"]:
                    if cha["channel_label"] == "ch_"+str(no_of_channel):
                        end_time = cha["end_time"]
                        if "start_time" in word:
                            if cha["items"]:
                                for cha_item in cha["items"]:
                                    if word["end_time"] == cha_item["end_time"] and word["start_time"] == cha_item["start_time"]:
                                        channel_text.append(word["alternatives"][0]["content"])
                                        flag = True
                        elif word["type"] == "punctuation":
                            if flag and channel_text:
                                temp = channel_text[-1]
                                temp += word["alternatives"][0]["content"]
                                channel_text[-1] = temp
                                flag = False
                                break

            channel_json["ch_"+str(no_of_channel)] = ' '.join(channel_text)
            channel_text = []
    print(channel_json)
    s3.put_object(Bucket="aws-speaker-separation", Key=file_name, Body=json.dumps(channel_json))

    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Channel transcript separated successfully!')
    }
```

However, when I run it, I get an error on line 23 saying:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'end_time'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 23, in lambda_handler
    end_time = cha["end_time"]
```

I am confused as to why this error is happening as in my JSON code, the things to read are as follows:

[JSON Code Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bVj.png)

Any ideas why this error is appearing?

Comment: use `print(cha)` to see if key `"end_time"` really exists. Maybe you have different value in `cha` than you expect.

Comment: see you JSON again. You don't have `cha['end_time']` but `cha['items'][0]['end_time']` (or `cha_item["end_time"]`, eventually `word['end_time']`)

Comment: @furas Thank you very much, that worked! It has now popped up again but on line 27 with the following error: `[ERROR] KeyError: 'end_time'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
    if word["end_time"] == cha_item["end_time"] and word["start_time"] == cha_item["start_time"]:`

Comment: you may have the same problem - you use item which doesn't have key `'end_time'` so use `print()` to check values in variables - maybe I was wrong and `word` doesn't have key `end_time`. Always when you have error use `print()` to check values in variables - it is called "print debugging"

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the help, really useful to know for future development! :)

Comment: @furas I have been looking and 'end_time' is present in both "word" and "cha_item" as well as "start_time", any ideas why this error is appearing?

Comment: there is list with items. Maybe one of the items doesn't have `end_time`. Maybe it didn't end yet. I would use `print()` to display `word` and `cha_item` (or `word.keys()` and `cha_item.keys()`) before line which makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

cha is a channel, the end_time is a layer deeper in the items of your channel. To access the items of your channel do:

```
for item in cha["items"]:
    print(item["end_time"])
```